# calculus 2: volume of solid of revolution formed by rotation of region

Tags: calculus, rotations

Find the integral for the volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating the region $R$ bounded by the curves $y = 4+x^2,\;x=0,\;y=0,\;and\;x=1\;$ about the $x$-axis **in terms of $dx $ and $ dy$**

Here is the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rij8mhgszd

I am still learning this so I would appreciate details! Thanks.

Edit:

Is this correct for dy?:
$$A=\pi(\sqrt{y-4})^2 \\V=\pi\int_0^1(y-4)dy=\\\pi\big(\frac{y^2}2-4y\big)\left.\right\vert_{0}^{1}=\\\pi\big(\frac12-4\big)-0=\boxed{-3\frac{1}{2}\pi}$$

Comment: Do you have the formula for this case?

Comment: The answer below provides a formula for solving this type of problem, however, I am still unsure on how to solve this in terms of dy and not dx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating the curve $y=f(x)$ between $x=a$ and $x=b$ about the $x$-as is given by

$$\pi\int_a^b(f(x))^2\,dx$$

Hence, the volume in your problem is given by $$\pi\int_0^1(4+x^2)^2\,dx$$

Can you work out this integral?

---

**Worked out solution:**

> $$\pi\int_0^1(4+x^2)^2\,dx=\pi\int_0^116+8x^2+x^4\,dx=\pi\big(16x+\frac83x^2+\frac15x^5\big)\left.\right\vert_{0}^{1}=\pi\big(16+\frac83+\frac15\big)=\boxed{18\frac{13}{15}\pi}$$

Comment: so, this is for dx? How would you solve this over the x-axis in terms of dy then?

Comment: in terms of dy would the integral be the same but from the range -4 to 4? or would the curve (radius) just be x = sqrt(y-4)?

Comment: @Jessica, the volume of the solid of revolution revolved about the $x$-axis isn't expressible in terms of $dy$. The volume of the solid of revolution revolved about the $y$-axis is. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, the problem is asking for the volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating the region R bounded by the (same) curves about the x-axis in terms of dy

Comment: with that in mind, do you think that it is asking to make the curve into $x=\sqrt(y-4)$? If that is the case, I got $-\frac{3\pi}2$

Comment: Yes, if it asked for the volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating about the $y$-axis, then your method and your solution are correct.

Comment: Well the next question asks for the same curves and a region rotated along the y-axis. So, I guess the question becomes: do they have the same answer or is the first one no solution?

Comment: They don't have the same answer. $18\frac{13}{15}\pi$ is the solution for the rotation about the $x$-axis, your solution is the solution for the rotation about the $y$-axis.

Comment: your solution is correct for the rotation around the x-axis with respect to dx, that was the first question. The second is the exact same, but with respect to dy (which is what I'm help up on). The third is the rotation around the y-axis, which I've figured out.