# Rotate about the x-axis with respect to dy

Tags: calculus, integration, rotations

How would I rotate the region bounded by $y = 4+x^2,\;x=0,\;y=0,\;and\;x=1\;$ **along the x-axis in terms of dy**. I have already solved this problem in terms of dx [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930059/calculus-2-volume-of-solid-of-revolution-formed-by-rotation-of-region)

Here is the graph:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rij8mhgszd

Comment: The link you posted showing how you solved it in terms of dx appears to actually be solved in terms of dy. Unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating with respect to $y$ is (in this case) a little more complicated. We use the Method of Cylindrical Shells.

The solid consists of two parts: (i) the part obtained by rotating the part of the region that lies below $y=4$ and (ii) the part obtained by rotating the part of the region that lies above $y=4$.

For (i) we could integrate but there is no need to do so. We get a cylinder with radius $4$ and height $1$, and therefore volume $16\pi$.

For (ii), take a thin slice of width "$dy$" at height $y$, where $y$ is between $4$ and $5$. Rotate the slice about the $x$-axis. We get a cylindrical shell of "thickness" $dy$,  radius $y$, and "height" $1-x$, which is $1-\sqrt{y-4}$. Thus the volume of (ii) is
$$\int_{y=4}^5 2\pi y\left(1-\sqrt{y-4}\right)\,dy.$$

Calculate, and add the $16\pi$ obtained earlier.

Comment: In your second statement "consists of two parts...", is that derived from a rotation around the y-axis?

Comment: The rotation is about the $x$-axis, as you specified in the problem.  Rotation about $y$-axis is a different problem, with a different answer.  I am sure you have drawn a picture. Draw also the line $y=4$. When the part below the line $y=4$ is rotated about the $x$-axis, we get a cylinder. We could find the colume of this cylinder by Shells, so integration with respect to $y$, and if you feel like it. You will get $\int_0^4 2\pi y\,dy$. I did not bother, since we don't really need integration for this part.  For the other part we do, so I set it up in detail.

Comment: Ah, okay. This helps a lot, Thanks very much!

Comment: Would you mind explaining the "height" 1-x part?

Comment: You are welcome. I assume we are both looking at similar pictures. We took a thin horizontal strip of negligible thickness $dy$, at height $y$, where $y$ is between $4$ and $5$. The strip starts hitting our region at $x$, where $y=x^2+4$, and goes on all the way to $1$. So the "length" of the strip is $1$ minus the part up to $x$, which is not in our region. The length of the strip, which is $1-x$, that is, $1-\sqrt{y-4}$, is the "height" of the cylindrical shell swept out by the strip as it rotates about the $x$-axis.

Comment: Awesome, I get it now. Thanks again.

Comment: These things are all about visualization. The main problem that students have is trying to use canned formulas. The problem you were given is a good one, since it asks you to control the geometry enough to answer two pairs of questions (rotation about each axis, each time two ways).